# How to get the value from customised forEach function returned to be used in callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback, return

Let's say myArray is as follows:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
```

And I would like my outcome to be as follows when 'map' is applied as follows:

```
map(myArray, function(val){
return val * 2;
});
//[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I have been able to do it with the following codes:

```
var map = function(collection,callback){
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        newArray.push(callback(collection[i]));
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

However, if I have customised the 'forEach' function earlier(as shown below) and would like to use my customised 'forEach' function in my 'map' function, how can I do it?

```
var forEach = function(collection,callback){
    if(Array.isArray(collection)){
        for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
            callback(collection[i]);
            }
    } else {
        for(var prop in collection){
            callback(collection[prop]);
            }
    }
 };
```

I have difficulty in getting the value from customised forEach function 'returned' to be used in callback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would highly recommend providing the right `this` binding and additional arguments to the callbacks, they are very useful and without them, you can't do many of the things the "real" [].map() can do. you should also skip through sparse arrays like [].map() does.

Comment: Consider invoking your callback like this and it will match up with [_Array.prototype.forEach_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `callback(collection[i], i, collection);` **edit** You may also want to do own property checking! `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call({foo:1}, 'foo');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could implement `map` using `forEach`:

```
var map = function(collection,callback){
    var newArray = [];
    forEach(collection, function(v) { 
        newArray.push(callback(v)); 
    });
    return newArray;
}
```